# css keyframes animation not initializing

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I've got a css @keyframe animation I'm trying to initiate but it never starts... What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/sadmicrowave/VKzXp/

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideNotificationsHide {
   0%{ width:70%; }
   100%{ width:94%; left:0; right:0; }
}

#left-container{ 
 position:aboslute; 
 top:0px; right:30%; 
 width:70%; height:100%; 
 border:1px solid green; 
 background:#eee; 
}

#left-container:target{ 
    background:green; 
    -webkit-animation: slideNotificationsHide .6s ease-in-out linear forwards; 
    -moz-animation: slideNotificationsHide .6s ease-in-out linear forwards; 
    animation: slideNotificationsHide .6s ease-in-out linear forwards; 
}


<div id='left-container'></div>
<a href="#left-container">click to start animation</a>
```

Notice the `background:green;` attribute/property in the `#left-container:target` declaration.  That portion actually works, so I know the `:target` is working; just not the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined both `animation-timing-function: linear;` and `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;` and you also had a typo in the `#left-container{ position:aboslute;}`

I've fixed the typo and removed `animation-timing-function: linear;` - is this how you want it ? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKzXp/1/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly. How would you go about stretching the left-container and then getting it to go back (with another click of course) all from using the same clickable link (like the anchor I've already got in the fiddle) with pure CSS? That's my next dilemma....

Comment: If you are looking for a click event I would suggest you using JavaScript instead. But, if you really just want to use pure CSS there are some hacks/tricks available, but I wouldn't recommend them for a live environment. Here's a post on CSS click events - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/ Glad I could help!